# Como calcular utilização para banco de dados no Microsoft Azure?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma onde conta com duas partes, uma administrativa e outra aberta ao publico. 
A parte administrativa irá inserir usuários e algumas outras coisas.
Já o usuário irá acessar e interagir com a plataforma, realizando algumas avaliações.

Utilizo a um certo tempo, para outros projetos, a LocaWeb, porém pesquisando cheguei até Microsoft Azure.

Pensando no principio apenas em banco MS SQL, pesquisei sobre os planos que o Azure dispõe. Não entendi muito bem os cálculos, por hora, requisição... Fiquei na dúvida.

Então gostaria de saber como é realizado o cálculo do Azure para BD, e quais suas vantagens/diferenças em comparação com a LocaWeb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não conheço a fundo os planos da LocaWeb, por uma rápida pesquisa vi que eles oferecem [só o SQL Server 2008](http://www.locaweb.com.br/produtos/cloud-server/planos-pro.html) que é um ultrapassado (foram lançadas 3 versões após ele e a versão 2008 não tem mais [suporte convencional pela Microsoft](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=sql)).

Os planos para SQL Database no Azure são cobrados por hora, de acordo com o das Bases de Dados. O valor que você paga varia pela configuração que você deseja utilizar.

O plano mais básico suporta 5 bancos de dados com capacidade máxima de 2 GB e 7 dias de backup full (pode restaurar para qualquer instante) com valor aproximado de R$0,0155 a hora (ou ~R$12 por mês).

Uma tabela completa e atualizada com os valores para o SQL Database pode ser encontrado [aqui <sup>en</sup>](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/)

Não conheço os serviços da LocaWeb, porém com o valor cobrado na LocaWeb de 75,00 reais creio que o benefício de hospedar sua base de dados no Azure seja maior, ainda mais agora que o [Datacenter da Azure no Brasil](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/windows-azure-brasil/) já está disponível para o público.

Comment: O que não entendi é esse valor por hora. Isso varia de quanto minha aplicação vai usar? Ou é R$ 12,00 por mês sempre? Entrei em contato com a LocaWeb, é R$ 30,00 mensais por 1 banco de 100 mb.

Comment: Esse valor é referente a quanto tempo em horas seu banco de dados irá existir. Caso você crie uma base da dados e 8 horas depois você decida apagá-la, você pagará somente por oito horas.

Comment: @Felipe vale a pena um trial para acompanhar se o serviço irá te atender. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Comment: Ahhh e se eu mante-lo criado por 1 mês será ~R$12,00? Você recomenda o Azure, ou conhece outro lugar melhor?

Comment: Para SQL Server recomendo o Azure. A vantagem é que com poucos cliques você pode fazer um upgrade para uma base de dados mais "parruda" (pagando mais, óbvio) e caso deseje fazer um downgrade.

Comment: Quanto a hospedagem, vi que é meio caro no Azure, você conhece algum lugar mais em conta? Pra rodar Asp.net (C#).

Comment: @Felipe não conheço.